# Python and Internet Explorer (specific website)

Tags: python, internet-explorer

I am trying to use Python to open an IE instance, navigate to a particular site, and enter login credentials. I am currently trying to make IEC work, but am open to other options that do the same thing.

I am having trouble the last part (login) because the "button" does not seem to be recognized as such. It appears to be some sort of trigger that acts as a button (role="button")? I am not very familiar with this:

```
<a title="Click here to log in." class="focus-parent ajax-request need-focus-pageobject" role="button" href="../MyAccount/MyAccountUserLogin.asp?Referrer=&AjaxRequest=true">
```

Here is the code I have tried:

```
import IEC

ie = IEC.IEController()
ie.Navigate('https://efun.toronto.ca/torontofun/Start/Start.asp')
ie.PollWhileBusy()
# code after here does not work properly
ie.Navigate('https://efun.toronto.ca/torontofun/MyAccount/MyAccountUserLogin.asp?Referrer=&AjaxRequest=true')
ie.ClickButton(caption='toolbar-login')
ie.SetInputValue('ClientBarcode', '123')
ie.SetInputValue('AccountPIN', 'XYZ')
ie.ClickButton(name='Enter')
```

I would appreciate tips on how to open the login menu in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [selenium](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PythonBindings) ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Ie()

login_btn = driver.find_element_by_id("toolbar-login")
login_btn.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

user_name = driver.find_element_by_id("ClientBarcode")
user_name.sendKeys("user")
user_name.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I saw selenium, but had not tried it. I want something that can control IE directly, and I did not think selenium could do this. (I thought it was mostly automated processes using text responses etc.) Did I misunderstand the abilities of selenium?

Comment: i am not sure about that, it was not mentioned on the question so i thought selenium could have been an option